# Keep animated View at final Animation Position

Tags: android, animation

So I'm animating a view using animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-75%" />

</set>
```

It does visually what I want but I also I want to freeze result of this animation. Like I need somehow to get resulting layout parameters (or something else?) after animation and set it to layout. Assume layout Y-coord is changing from 0 to 100 but I don't really know what was starting coords and what are resulting coords. I need to get resulting coords and set it to the layout cuz if wouldn't do so layout returns back to its initial position after animation but I need to make it stay in new position instead of returning back. Also I need 2.3.x compatible solution.
**UPDATE 1**
I also tried NineOldAndroids:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rootWrapper, "translationY", -rootWrapper.getHeight()*75/100).start();
```

this animates the view and view stays at animated position - thats exactly what I want to achieve.
 However all controls stays at their positions virtually. Even thou layout is only visible by 25% of its bottom part and 75% of rest screen looks empty if I tap that empty screen area then button's (which was there b4 animation) onClick triggered. The same happens with xml-animtaions if set

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

How to fix that issue? All controls has to move with the view.
**UPDATE 2**
The code:

```
    public void showAbout(){

        final Animation animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.about_in_from_bottom);
        animShow.setFillAfter(true); 

        //ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rootWrapper, "translationY", -rootWrapper.getHeight()*75/100).start();

        animShow.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams rootlp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rootWrapper.getLayoutParams();
                Log.i(this,"rootlp: h: "+rootlp.topMargin+ " / w: "+rootlp.bottomMargin);
                rootlp.topMargin = -rootlp.height*75/100;
                rootWrapper.setLayoutParams(rootlp);
            }
        });

        rootWrapper.startAnimation(animShow);
    }
```

I got the problem - `rootlp.height` returns 0 cuz its like MATCH_PARENT or like. It wont return the REAL pixels but some value representing some constant! So it looks like I have 2 play with `.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener`.
Ok, I got the real height of rootWrapper via getViewTreeObserver(). And now using the formula `rootlp.topMargin = -rootlp.height*75/100;` I'm getting even more issues.
 1) After animation View moves up additionally (due to setting LP).
2) Controls that animated View contains (buttons which has to move up with the parent View) stays at their positions virtually (they are invisible but clickable)! Visually those controls are moved up with the animated View and I can't reach it (it goes off the screen). But if I tap area where they was before animation corresponding onClick() triggers! What a fun!
**UPDATE 3**
Finally I had achieved my goal! The problem was with moving View's child containers. I was thinking that if I move some View then all of its child views are also moving. But thats not the case and I was had to move child views manually after animation completes to fix ghost buttons.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the LayoutParams after the animation? Do you want the View to stay at the animated position?

Comment: yeah, Exactly what I want 2do.

Comment: Well then see my anser and use setFillAfter();

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Please consider **setFillAfter(boolean);** setting it to true will make the view stay at the animated position.

```
Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 100);

// or like this
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation_name);

anim.setFillAfter(true); 
anim.setDuration(1000);
```

This can be done even easier using the **ViewPropertyAnimator**, available from API 14 and onwards:

```
int animationpos = 500;
View.animate().y(animationpos).setDuration(1000); // this will also keep the view at the animated position
```

Or consider an **AnimationListener** to get the LayoutParams exactly after the animation:

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                  // get layoutparams here and set it in this example your views 
                  // parent is a relative layout, please change that to your desires

                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) View.getLayoutParams();
                  lp.topMargin = yournewtopmargin // use topmargin for the y-property, left margin for the x-property of your view
                  View.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
            });

    View.startAnimation(anim);
```

**UPDATE:**

> How to know how many pixels the view moved, depending on the
>   percentage values of the animation?

**The percentage value in your .xml animation is relative to the animated View's dimensions (such as width and height).** Therefore, you just need to use **your View's width and height properties** (depending on weather u use x or y animation to get the actual animation distance in pixels).

For example:

Your View has a width of 400 pixels. Your animation animates the x-property from 0% to 75%, meaning that your view will move 300 pixels (400 * 0.75) to the right side. So onAnimationEnd(), set the LayoutParams.leftMargin to 300 and your View will have the desired position.

Comment: thanx! anim.setFillAfter(true); does the trick BUT all the controls stays virtually (invisible) at their positions. Check my update 1 in question.

Comment: see the animationlistener and especially the animationEnd method in my answer :) you can get the layoutParams and set it adequately

Comment: Yeah, but how to know the animation resulting yournewtopmargin? That was the part of my question cuz I already tried to set LP in onAnimationEnd before asking the question but stuck with the value to set.

Comment: thanx again, I tried rootlp.topMargin = -rootlp.height*100/75; and rootWrapper.setLayoutParams(rootlp); but no luck - invisible controls are still there...

Comment: What do you mean by invisible controls are still there? Could you post your code in your question.

Comment: Allright, have you checked if lp.height is >0? also use lp.topMargin = lp.topMargin + animationdistance;

Answer (score 2):

I find that simply setting fillEnabled and fillAfter to TRUE does not solve the issue when things like click/touch listeners are involved. Setting fill enabled and fill after to be true just ensures that the pixels of the view are DRAWN in the correct final place. However, suppose the view being animated has a onclick listener associated with it. Clicking the view in its new visible position will do nothing, however clicking the screen in the position the view was originally will trigger the onClick.

The following is an example of how to get around this:

Suppose we have a view with an onClickListener set to it. Suppose also that the views bounds are 0, 0, 0, 0 (left, top, right, bottom).
Suppose now we wish to move the view to the right by 200. The following code will demonstrate how to do this in a manner that will move both the pixels to be drawn and the underlying view object to the correct position, hence adjusting the onClick to be called from the correct position.

```
private Animation generateMoveRightAnimation() {
    final Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 200,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
    animation.setDuration(300);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setFillEnabled(true);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            // change the coordinates of the view object itself so that on click listener reacts to new position
            view.layout(view.getLeft()+200, view.getTop(), view.getRight()+200, view.getBottom());
            repeatLevelSwitch.clearAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    return animation;
}
```

Comment: @BiGGZ You mean I need to add more detail?

Comment: im trying this by the way, and its not working. My touch event is still being dispatched to the old position. And the `lp` object isnt being used anywhere

Comment: Honestly it's been a while since I did this but I strongly recommend this entire paradigm for animations to begin with. I suggest using ObjectAnimators instead. This API is far better than this old Animation stuff.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NineOldAndroid](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) proxy library for using ObjectAnimator as you wish. it supports lower api levels and uses the native library for newer api levels.

Just simply import as LibraryProject and it will be all good.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question I already tried that. This causes some issue about ghost controls also described in my Q.