# Android Sliding animation on fragment

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to achieve a slide_up animation on a fragment when I do a button press on one of the views of the bottom bar it just slides up and disappears I want the bottom bar to just slide up and not disappear.

Here's my code

```
  ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mBottomBar, "translationY", 0f, -150f);
  objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
  objectAnimator.start();
```

here mBottomBar is a reference to the bottom bar fragment.

Comment: You can try setting setFillAfter() to be true for the animation to remain after transformation. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269338/keep-animated-view-at-final-animation-position