# View's Properties not changing with Property Animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to animate a floating action button to a new location and have it be clickable there, but when I animate it via

```
listOptionsButton.animate().xBy(-200);
```

I can't click it in the new location that it goes to.

I thought that using this kind of animation would move the view itself and not just the rendered pixels.

Can someone explain what's happening and help me find a way to move my button and be able to click it at the start and end locations?

Comment: When you Animate any view (button) etc , Its physical position within Layout remains same , for this you have to change there physical location too .

Comment: Below Link has Complete solution of your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269338/keep-animated-view-at-final-animation-position

Comment: So, you're saying I should add a listener and then update the margins onAnimationEnd?  I'm pretty sure I tried that, but I'll try it again.

Comment: I did use `offsetLeftAndRight()` and `offsetTopAndBottom()` using an AnimationListener with a regular TranslateAnimation but after my animation ended the view and the rendered portion "jumped" at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue.  It turns out that I animated the button outside of the parent layout and even though I used property animation, the button wasn't reachable because it was outside of the bounds of the parent.

I don't know how to elaborate further, because I honestly don't fully understand why this was an issue, but I ended up making a compound view that took up my entire screen so it wasn't an issue in the end.