# Android translate animation is different the second time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I created a very simple translate animation, when the button is pressed for the first time, an image view will move to the left, and the second it will move to the right. The distance is exactly the same.

But the second time the image moves more and actually doesn't come back to its original position. To be more accurate, the second time the image goes twice the distance. Why?

```
private var direction = 1
fun move() {
    val animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationX", direction*(-100f))
    val animatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationY", 0f)
    animatorX.duration = (500)
    animatorY.duration = (500)
    val animationSet = AnimatorSet()
    animationSet.playTogether(animatorX, animatorY)
    animationSet.start()
    if (direction == 1) {direction = -1} else {direction = 1}
}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        button.setOnClickListener{move()}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the second time the image goes twice the distance

Because after first animation its x position is (initial x - 100) and the second time you are animating x to 100 . So second time its going -100 to 100 and its twice distance from first

For moving right set translationX to 0

```
private var direction = 1
fun move() {

    var distance = -100f
    if (direction == -1){
        distance = 0f
    }

    val animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationX", distance)
    val animatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationY", 0f)

    animatorX.duration = (500)
    animatorY.duration = (500)
    val animationSet = AnimatorSet()
    animationSet.playTogether(animatorX, animatorY)
    animationSet.start()
    if (direction == 1) {direction = -1} else {direction = 1}
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    button.setOnClickListener{move()}
}
```

Comment: didn't you think "animatorY" is useless here.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel you are right I just copy the code and changed what the question ask about

Comment: Oh I'm so stupid I was sure that the value is the distance and not the position-to, now it all makes sense thank you very much

Comment: Yes it's useless here sorry about that I didn't notice it in the code here

Comment: @AbuYousuf I'm sorry it's not the position but seems like an accumulated distance that the animation is accumulating? Is it possible to reset this value with each animation? I don't want the animation to "remember" the distance it made the last time, is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @sir-haver check this anser for reset https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269477/1292557

Comment: @AbuYousuf thanks I checked this link but didn't find a way to reset, could you please direct me to where the reset is explained? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code for animation, try this updated answer.

```
val animatorX: ObjectAnimator?
    if (direction == 1) {
        direction = -1
        animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, "translationX", -100f)
    } else {
        direction = 1
        animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, "translationX", 200f)
    }
    animatorX.duration = 500
    animatorX.start()
```

Comment: I'm not interested in making a reverse animation. I need to translate the image to the left and then to the right at different times, hence my question thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do hope that there is a way to reset the animator, but if not I did find a workaround for this. You should get the inital coordinates and then use it to calculate the translation:

```
val animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationX", (draggableImage1.x - initalLeft) -(direction*100f))
```